Security of RSW96 Timelock puzzles
I am looking to implement Time lock puzzles in a toy project I'm working on. I found this very elegant paper from Rivest et at. describing a technique for time lock puzzles. I'm wondering if the scheme is still considered secure these days.
For example:

Is RC5 still a secure and used encryption algorithm?
Is the assumption that performing sequential squaring is an "intrinsically sequential" operation still valid?


What is the progress on the MIT LCS35 Time Capsule Crypto-Puzzle?

To the author: does that answer your question? I'd guess that solving it with a FPGA went faster than expected, but that the squaring is still a sequential op as DW stated. The security of RC5 is another matter, but please remember that any dents in the security of a cipher won't directly lead to a practical attack unless the cipher is really broken.
